# Chinese character doesn't support for Sqlite3 through CGI script

Tags: python, sqlite, cgi

inserting Chinese character into Sqlite3 through Cgi script is not working for me. I can insert and select Chinese character from same database using Query browser tool but when I use python script for this, it's show error.  This is the query i have used for create database

`CREATE TABLE registrations ( 
    m_username   VARCHAR  PRIMARY KEY
                          COLLATE 'BINARY',
    m_identity   VARCHAR,
    m_updatetime DATETIME 
);`

and then this is the cgi script i have used for update and select values form the database

```
#! /Python26/python
dbFile = 'D:/sqlite/registrations'
import cgi
import sqlite3
import xml.sax.saxutils

 query = cgi.parse()
db = sqlite3.connect(dbFile)

user = query.get('username', [None])[0]
identity = query.get('identity', [None])[0]
friends = query.get('friends', [])
print 'Content-type: text/plain\n\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n'

print "<result>"

if user:
try:
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("insert or replace into registrations values (?, ?,      datetime('now'))", (user, identity))
    print "\t<update>true</update>"
except:
    print '\t<update>false</update>'

for f in friends:
print "\t<friend>\n\t\t<user>%s</user>" % (xml.sax.saxutils.escape(f), )
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("select m_username, m_identity from registrations where m_username = ? and m_updatetime > datetime('now', '-1 hour')", (f, ))
for result in c.fetchall():
    eachIdent = result[1]
    if not eachIdent:
        eachIdent = ""
    print "\t\t<identity>%s</identity>" % (xml.sax.saxutils.escape(eachIdent), )
    if f != result[0]:
        print "\t\t<registered>%s</registered>" % (xml.sax.saxutils.escape(result[0]), )
print "\t</friend>"
db.commit()

print "</result>"
```

I think, i need to set CHARSET as UTF-8 something, but I don't know how to do it. i was googled, but couldn't find good way to solve this issue. kindly some one help me please.

Comment: "it's show error." Awesome. Feel like sharing?

Comment: Not really about this question, but please, sir, use a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this through the client side. I just used EncodeBase64 and encoded the chinese data and send to the db. I think, this one is not straight way. but I couldn't find any other way.